# Android setting pivot point for scale animation

Tags: android, animation, pivot

I am trying to scale views to a certain size but can't quite understand how pivoting works.

Say I want to scale the view upwards only. What value should the "pivotY" hold? In XML, it is a percentage. How is it when applying pivot point programmatically?

Example:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", scaleSize);
ObjectAnimator pivotY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "pivotY", pivotPoint);

AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.PlayTogether(scaleY, pivotY);
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Quite simple actually.

If you want to scale upwards one clear option is:

```
 view.setPivotY(100);
```

and downwards:

```
 view.setPivotY(0);
```

then animate.

Comment: what to do for <11 support?

Comment: Not quite THAT simple.  First, **Setting this property disables this behavior and causes the view to use only the explicitly set pivotX and pivotY values.**  Also, the values used aren't percentages, they *Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).* (from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: @TalMihr Any idea how to scale Left and Right ?

Answer (score 12):

**Use:**

```
view.setPivotY(view.getMeasuredHeight());
```

If you need to animate your object from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your pivot point takes your view as reference. So a pivot point set at 0,0 means it matches the top left side of your view.

So this animation:

```kotlin
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1f, 0f)
```

Will be affected by `pivotY`

```kotlin
view.pivotY = 0 // will shrink the view towards the view top
view.pivotY = view.measuredHeight.toFloat() // will shrink the view towards the view bottom
view.resetPivot() // will shrink the view towards the center
```

In the same way, this animation:

```kotlin
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1f, 0f)
```

Will be affected by `pivotX`

```kotlin
view.pivotX = 0 // will shrink the view towards the view left
view.pivotX = view.measuredHeight.toFloat() // will shrink the view towards the view right
view.resetPivot() // will shrink the view towards the center
```

Comment: your answer is the best!